# Confusing Union construct

Tags: c++

In the below piece of code :

```
union
{
float dollars;
int yens;
}price;
```

Is price an instance of an anonymous union or is it the name of the union itself. It looks to me like an instance but the author of the code says it's
the name of the union.

Now, the second question - Suppose if this union is embedded in a structure
like below:

```
struct
{
char title[50];
char author[50];
union
{
float dollars;
int yens;
}price;
}book1;
```

Would an access **book1.dollars** be valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It is an instance of an anonymous union indeed, the author was wrong. If you prepend the union with a `typedef` keyword like

```
typedef union
{
   float dollars;
   int yens;
} price;
```

, then `price` will be a typename referring to the union.

2) Nope, `book1.price.dollars` you want to use instead.

**UPDATE:**
An union type can be declared in the following way either:

```
union price
{
   float dollars;
   int yens;
}; // here you see, there is no instance.
```

If there was an identifier between the closing brace and the semicolon, that would be the name of the instance.

Comment: But what if I wish too override the **price** instance?

Comment: I don't seem to understand your question. How to override an _instance_?

Comment: so in case of 1, without typedef price is a variable already ? I did not notice the missing typedef before ;-), do you happen to know why this would be usefull ?

Comment: @Géza Török : say, what if I don't want to use this instance?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Yes it is a variable already :) I could explain some use cases where it is very handy but a comment is not the place where I can do so, it's a bit longer, needs examples, etc. Create a question and i'll be there :)

Comment: @sjsam there are two ways to declare a type without specifying an instance initially. The first is the one I mentioned in my answer, with `typedef`, the second one is the way how you declare classes. Please have a look @ my update in a minute :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250665/what-is-the-use-case-for-an-anonymous-union-type is my question ;-)

Comment: @GézaTörök : Declaring classes without an object - the method you pointed out  by your edit - is obvious. But, to put it this way, suppose we don't put `typedef` in front, thus creating anonymous union, it sounds strange to create a instance of such a union. Aint it?

Comment: No it isn't. In fact it is very useful, and if beloved SO didn't close the question of @PhilipStuyck, I would have provided a detailed explanation on this... :(

Comment: I voted to reopen, they link to an explanation of union with typedef.